# Use a script to copy the formatting of another column in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I have a series of values in one column (human heights, in this instance), which I have made as human-readable as possible. I want to color-code these, however, so I have a second column right next to it, where I have typed out these heights as pure numbers, which I have then applied a color scale (conditional formatting) to. Normally, it would be somewhat easy to have conditional formatting based on another cell, by using a custom formula, but with the color scale feature, there isn't a way to input conditions (at least that I'm aware of).

As such, I want to try copying the formatting from the pure-number column to the human-readable column (then I can just hide the former). Unfortunately, since this is conditional formatting, I can't just copy over the colors directly, since they'll change based on the new cell values. I know that Google Sheets supports some sort of scripting, so I figured there must be some way to set the current background/fill color of one cell to match that of another automatically, which can also update if that other cell's formatting changes. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do any of this scripting stuff, so I wanted to ask here if anyone can help me figure that out.

Edit: [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18EZxqilkZ-67-Em__vym1M0ndskw8RzU4bG06wcwNRE/edit?usp=sharing)'s a very basic example of what I have now. What I'm trying to do is apply the same formatting as on the right to the left without changing the values.

Comment: Kindly share a sample spreadsheet and the desired output.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18EZxqilkZ-67-Em__vym1M0ndskw8RzU4bG06wcwNRE/edit?usp=sharing) you are, I want to somehow assign the left the same coloring as the right without changing the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. In your Spreadsheet, go to **Tools** -> **Script Editor**
2. Delete any code in the script editor
3. Paste the code provided below.
4. Press Run button

**Code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sourceBG = sh.getRange("B2:B8").getBackgrounds();
  sh.getRange("A2:A8").setBackgrounds(sourceBG);
}
```

*Note: Just change the range if you have more rows and make sure that the source and destination range have the same size.*

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [Range.getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)
- [Range.setBackgrounds(color)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor)